# How to call a method from a different blueprint in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I have an application with multiple blueprinted modules.

I would like to call a method (a route) that would normally return a view or render a template, from within a different blueprint's route.

How can this be done correctly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Views are just functions; import the function and call it directly, passing in any route parameters that it may have defined.

The role of the Blueprint is to make it easier to register a group of routes under a common prefix, group their templates and static resources, and handle request-related events for just that group (request started, request completed, etc.). But how you call a view doesn't change.

For example, if you have a route in the `foo` blueprint, in the `foo.py` module:

```
@foo.route('/bar/<id>')
def bar(id):
    return something_done_with_id(id)
```

you can import that function and use it elsewhere:

```
import foo

@baz.route('/spam/ham/eggs'):
def baz():
    return foo.bar(42)
```

Here `bar` takes a parameter from the URL, named `id`, so when calling the view function we do need to pass in a value for that parameter.

Do note that any blueprint `before_request`, `after_request` and `context_processor` functions are not executed (that happens at routing time), nor are Blueprint-specific error handlers in effect.

Comment: What does it mean to have "route parameters it may have defined"? Thank you.

Comment: @Phil: I've added some more context for you to elaborate on that.

Comment: What about methods that require query string or body content?

Comment: @cnelson: create a new request context with [`app.request_context()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.request_context) in a `with` statement and call the other function.